# Spring Boot 2 - Testing @Cacheable with Mockito for method without arguments is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-cache

I have an application using Spring Boot 2. I would like to test a method with **@Cacheable** (Spring Cache) on it. I made a simple example in order to show the idea:

```
@Service
public class KeyService {

    @Cacheable("keyCache")
    public String getKey() {
        return "fakeKey";
    }
}
```

And the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class KeyServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private KeyService keyService;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnTheSameKey() {

        Mockito.when(keyService.getKey()).thenReturn("key1", "key2");

        String firstCall = keyService.getKey();
        assertEquals("key1", firstCall);

        String secondCall = keyService.getKey();
        assertEquals("key1", secondCall);
    }

    @EnableCaching
    @Configuration
    static class KeyServiceConfig {

        @Bean
        KeyService keyService() {
            return Mockito.mock(KeyService.class);
        }

        @Bean
        CacheManager cacheManager() {
            return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("keyCache");
        }
    }
}
```

The example above does not work. But, if I change the `getKey()` method to receive a parameter:

```
@Service
public class KeyService {

    @Cacheable("keyCache")
    public String getKey(String param) {
        return "fakeKey";
    }
}
```

And refactor the test to accommodate that change, the test works successfully:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class KeyServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private KeyService keyService;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnTheSameKey() {

        Mockito.when(keyService.getKey(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("key1", "key2");

        String firstCall = keyService.getKey("xyz");
        assertEquals("key1", firstCall);

        String secondCall = keyService.getKey("xyz");
        assertEquals("key1", secondCall);
    }

    @EnableCaching
    @Configuration
    static class KeyServiceConfig { //The same code as shown above }
}
```

Do you guys have any idea about this issue?

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem @vallim
I tried `@Cacheable(value = "keyCache", key = "#root.methodName")`, suggestion given by it doesnt seem to work

Comment: From mockito 5.x.x, `when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.``,  Autowire on KeyService should be mock

Answer (score 2):

a cache lookup is performed using as key the method parameters. It means you need a key for methods that don't have params. Try this `@Cacheable(value = "keyCache", key = "#root.methodName")`

Comment: I tried your solution, it still doesnt work?
Any suggestions? @Bizon4ik

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reliably test method wrapped with cacheable of spy/mock bean.

Longer answer: Those two proxies are conflicting with each other, so you need to extract Cacheable on method of higher level bean and mock bean should be inside of that method.