# How to test Spring @Cacheable using customized key with SpEL

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-el, spring-cache

I was looking for a way to test some of my @Cacheable and @CacheEvict methods and I've found out a very good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24229350/4534078).

However, my case is a bit different and trickier.

So, using the code from that post as example, I've added a cache key using spEL:

```
  interface MyRepo {
    @Cacheable(value = "sample", key = "#email.concat('.').concat(#email)")
    Object findByEmail(String email);
  }
```

Now, when trying to use Mockito.when(...):

```
  Mockito
    .when(repo.findByEmail(Mockito.any(String.class)))
    .thenReturn(first, second);
```

I got this spEl exception:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method concat(java.lang.String) on null context object
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.throwIfNotNullSafe(MethodReference.java:144)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:95)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:85)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:57)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:87)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:242)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheOperationExpressionEvaluator.key(CacheOperationExpressionEvaluator.java:117)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContext.generateKey(CacheAspectSupport.java:742)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.generateKey(CacheAspectSupport.java:558)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:502)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:389)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:327)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at techne.cronos.$Proxy36.findByEmail(Unknown Source)
    at techne.cronos.CachingIntegrationTest.methodInvocationShouldBeCached(CachingIntegrationTest.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)
```

Does anyone have some guidance on how to pass through this testing issue?

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `Mockito.any(String.class))` return null, Always this expression will give you null (try some print and check)

The concat method on the Spel require not null object

Use a hard coded string as an argument to `findByEmail` and your problem is gone

In case you want to know more about Mockito.any(..) check [doc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Matchers.html#any(java.lang.Class))

Cheers

Comment: I thought that either, but it is not true. I've tried Mockito.when(repo.findByEmail("something")).thenReturn(first, second); and the error prevails.