# Spring Cacheable implementing class

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to somehow 'debug' my application that use the spring boot cache annotations and for that I would like to know how to find the class that actually implements the interface Cacheable, CacheConfig, etc.

My idea is to confirm that the cache is being populated, emptied etc.

Thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: This answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24229350/2387977

Comment: Thanks you but if I could debug and see somehow in 'real-time' the cache content etc it might be simpler for me

Answer (score 2):

`@Cacheable` is used to demarcate methods that are cacheable - that is, methods for whom the result is stored into the cache so on subsequent invocations (with the same arguments), the value in the cache is returned without having to actually execute the method. In its simplest form, the annotation declaration requires the name of the cache associated with the annotated method:

```
@Cacheable("books")
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn) {...}
```

In the snippet above, the method findBook is associated with the cache named books. Each time the method is called, the cache is checked to see whether the invocation has been already executed and does not have to be repeated. While in most cases, only one cache is declared, the annotation allows multiple names to be specified so that more than one cache are being used. In this case, each of the caches will be checked before executing the method - if at least one cache is hit, then the associated value will be returned.

For more information read the following;

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache

Spring used `ConcurrentHashMap` as the default cache implementation.

```
public class ConcurrentMapCache extends AbstractValueAdaptingCache
```

If, on the other hand, you need different cache, then Spring also comes with a built in `ehCache` wrapper. The good news is that swapping between Spring's caching implementations is easy. In theory it’s all a matter of configuration.

Comment: Thank you I'm aware of the way it works but what I'd like to know is how is the cache content etc in runtime, i believe this is possible with the springboot/eclipse debug mode, however I don't know the implementing class