# How do I test a Spring Data Rest @RepositoryRestResource?

Tags: repository, mockito, spring-data-rest

I was trying to set up unit testing for a REST API built with Spring Data Rest. I have a repository like this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface BeerRepository extends JpaRepository<Beer, Long> {
}
```

My test looks like this:

```
public class BeerRestTest extends AbstractRestTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("beerRepositoryMock")
    protected BeerRepository beerRepositoryMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        super.setUp();
        Mockito.reset(beerRepositoryMock);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetBeer() throws Exception {
        Beer beer = new Beer();
        beer.setId(1L);
        beer.setName("Duff");

        when(beerRepositoryMock.findOne(1L)).thenReturn(beer);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/beers/{id}", 1L))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

        verify(beerRepositoryMock, times(1)).findOne(1L);
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(beerRepositoryMock);
    }

}
```

and the spring data rest configuration looks like this:

```
public class RestConfig extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer() {
        return new RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
                config.setBasePath("/api");
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Finally, the logs

```
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReferenceCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[PATCH || PUT || POST],consumes=[application/json || application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.createPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<java.lang.Object>,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReferenceId(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.optionsForCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResourceCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}],methods=[POST],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.postCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}/{id}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.optionsForItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}/{id}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headForItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}/{id}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.Resource<?>> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PUT],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.putItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PATCH],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.patchItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}/{id}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.deleteItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/ || /api],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.headForRepositories()
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/ || /api],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.optionsForRepositories()
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/ || /api],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryLinksResource> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.listRepositories()
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}/search],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.optionsForSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}/search],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}/search],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchesResource org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.listSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearchCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.optionsForSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.lang.String)
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.lang.String)
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/profile/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/schema+json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.JsonSchema> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySchemaController.schema(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/profile/{repository}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/alps+json]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController.alpsOptions()
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/profile/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/alps+json || */*]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController.descriptor(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/profile],methods=[OPTIONS]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController.profileOptions()
2016-01-12 23:33:10 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/profile],methods=[GET]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController.listAllFormsOfMetadata()
2016-01-12 23:33:11 [main] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/api/beers/15] in DispatcherServlet with name ''

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /api/beers/1
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :404
 <Click to see difference>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:89)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$10.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:655)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
    at com.beerway.server.rest.BeerRestTest.testGetBeer(BeerRestTest.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

EDIT: beerRepositoryMock

```
@Bean(name = "beerRepositoryMock")
public BeerRepository beerRepositoryMock() {
    return Mockito.mock(BeerRepository.class);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show how you created the bean beerRepositoryMock .

Comment: @MathiasDpunkt done :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the way spring data rest looks up the repositories I cannot see a way of making spring data rest use your mock repository.

With your configuration you end up with two `BeerRepository` beans - the mock and the real one - spring data rest would look up this repository by the bean name `beerRepository`.

So I tried something like this:

```
@Bean
public BeerRepository beerRepository() {
    return Mockito.mock(BeerRepository.class);
}
```

But my bean is always overridden by the real repository bean.

I am using an in-memory db to insert my test data in my tests. That works fine and would be an easy alternative for you.

Comment: that would be more like an integration test right? I'm already doing that (h2 database), but I want to also unit test the repositories (I don't know if this is useful or not)

Comment: There is a very useful answer from one of the spring-data maintainers - he explains why it is not too useful to test the repos: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23442457/5371736

Comment: Also there is an answer in the same question that point to an implementation that claims to support testing repos - but I did not try it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28643025/5371736

Comment: @MatiasElorriaga This question is quite old, but in general you would not be unit testing the repository in any meaningful way with what you're going for. Unless you have provided a concrete repository implementation, the actual repository implementation is provided by Spring Data REST so you'd be testing their code.

Answer (score 0):

Since @RepositoryRestResource makes the REST repository a spring bean, you can use the Spring annotation:

```
@MockBean
RestRepository mockedRepository
```

then use mockito's

```
when(...mockedRepository.someMethod(any())).thenReturn(value)
```

Comment: how can you test the controller created by Spring Data Rest ?