# Mock Spring Data Rest Repository

Tags: spring, rest, unit-testing, spring-data-rest

I faced with problem while testing data rest repositories. I call rest resource and check if it gets me proper json. But for pre-population data I don't want to use in memory db, so I mocked repository method invocation.
`@MockBean
  private CommentRepository commentRepository;`
and did this

```
given(commentRepository.findOne(1L)).willReturn(comment);
```

And now, while calling "/comments/1" I get 404 error, so data rest didn't expose my repository. The main question is "How can we mock repository method for getting data from database?"

My test class:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class CommentTest
{
  @Autowired
  private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

  @MockBean
  private CommentRepository commentRepository;

  @Before
  public void setup()
  {
    Comment comment = new Comment();
    comment.setText("description");
    comment.setCommentId(1L);

    given(commentRepository.findOne(1L)).willReturn(comment);
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldCheckCommentGetResource()
  {
    ParameterizedTypeReference<Resource<Comment>> responseType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<Resource<Comment>>() {};

    ResponseEntity<Resource<Comment>> responseEntity =
        restTemplate.exchange("/comments/1", HttpMethod.GET, null, responseType, Collections
            .emptyMap());

    Comment actualResult = responseEntity.getBody().getContent();
    assertEquals("description", actualResult.getText());
    // more assertions
  }
}
```

As I understand, using MockBean annotation I replace current repository bean and it will not be exposed by data rest, Do we have any way to pre-populate data into db or mock invocation of repository method?

Comment: can you show us your test and the beans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible. Spring data registers the repository beans using a FactoryBean - in the spring-data-rest case this is `EntityRepositoryFactoryBean`. So you cannot just override these beans with a mock.

For an interesting read on why mocking spring data repositories is not useful see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23442457/5371736

In the same thread there is a reference to a project introducing mock support for spring-data repositories - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28643025/5371736

Answer (score 0):

There is quick and dirty way to mock Spring Data Rest repositories with mockito, just in case somebody have no other options, but try to avoid this unless absolutely necessary

```
class MockRestRepositoryUtil {
    public static <T> T mockRepository(Class<T> repositoryClass,
                                        T springRepository) throws Exception {
        Object springRepositoryImpl = AopTestUtils.getTargetObject(springRepository);
        T mockRepository = mock(repositoryClass, delegatesTo(springRepositoryImpl));
        Object springProxyHandler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(springRepository);
        ProxyFactory proxyFactory = extractProxyFactory(springProxyHandler);
        proxyFactory.setTarget(mockRepository);
        removeSpringDataAspects(proxyFactory);
        return mockRepository;
    }

    private static ProxyFactory extractProxyFactory(Object springProxyHandler) throws Exception {
        Field advisedField = springProxyHandler.getClass().getDeclaredField("advised");
        advisedField.setAccessible(true);
        return (ProxyFactory) advisedField.get(springProxyHandler);
    }

    private static void removeSpringDataAspects(ProxyFactory proxyFactory) {
        Advisor[] advisors = proxyFactory.getAdvisors();
        Arrays.stream(advisors)
            .filter(advisor -> advisor.getAdvice().getClass().getPackage().getName()
                .contains("org.springframework.data"))
            .collect(toImmutableList())
            .forEach(proxyFactory::removeAdvisor);
    }
}
```